# gitlab-pages: no files (artifacts) to archive, so no website

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to publish a static website with gitlab-pages. I carefully took inspiration from [the official jekyll example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/pages-jekyll) to write [my own](https://gitlab.com/vindarel/abelujo-website/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) gitlab-ci.yml.

My [build succeeds](https://gitlab.com/vindarel/abelujo-website/builds/528410), a `ls -l` shows that I do have a `public/` repository, however I have the message "archiving artifacts… no files to archive" and thus I can't find my website on `myusername.gitlab.com/myproject`.

I checked that the official example [still works](https://gitlab.com/vindarel/pages-jekyll/builds/523456). (However… I can't find where it's being published !)

I got no help on irc nor gitter.

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Maybe is it a matter of settings ? The doc states to enable the pages feature but there are hardly any checkboxe to click.

ps: that may be related to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/456 , which I see was fixed for v8.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! \o/

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:2.7.11

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - vendor

  script:
  - pip install Lektor
  - lektor build --output-path public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

---

UPDATE

You can also try this:

```
image: python:2.7

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - vendor

  stage: deploy
  script:
  - pip install Lektor
  - lektor build --output-path public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

I don't see you need a `before_script:` command, but if you want that, add to it `- pip install Lektor`.

Comment: works very well with `image: python:2.7` too :) You can also add `stage: deploy` but it's not required.

Comment: They updated the docs now, it's much better! http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html

Comment: I'll read them again then. What is the key difference with your yaml ? ([here's mine](https://gitlab.com/vindarel/abelujo-website/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)). I see you don't use `before_script` to install lektor but that's not an issue because I'm able to install it; and you use `cache`.

Comment: btw my last build (tried this afternoon after your answer) [succeeded](https://gitlab.com/vindarel/abelujo-website/builds/838452) but I see nothing about deployment :) Let's read the doc…

Comment: I believe it is something with the list command: `ls -l ; ls -l public` or with the build command: `lektor build -O public`  vs `lektor build --output-path public` but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yep, your build succeed but didn't generate `artifacts`. Was this on purpose?

Comment: I cloned your repo for testing and with this script the site was build successfully, that's why I came forward with this new answer... :)

Comment: You can check my build [here](https://gitlab.com/virtua-tests/lektor/builds/835353). I'll delete the repo soon. :)

Comment: Lol ! hahahaha I'm happy for you! :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question is easier that you thought.

Your website will be published at 
`https://username.gitlab.io/project_name`

Got it? It's not `gitlab.com`! :)

Don't worry, new guides to GitLab Pages are coming soon!

Comment: That's a valid point indeed, thank you ! However, my website isn't published. At the step "archiving archifacts", I have the message "no files to archive", where it should be done and followed by a "uploading artifacts" task (and I do have a 'public' directory).

Comment: Can you tell me your project's url? I can take a look.

Comment: Sorry, it's already on your post. I'll take a look later and get back to you.

Comment: I see. Your using Python, and I don't have any expertise on that. But what I do know that Jekyll 3 is based on  Ruby only. What you can try to do is calling for Jekyll 2.5.3 or Jekyll 2.4.0. I'll take a better look when I'm by my pc and get back to you.

Comment: Changing the stage to `deploy` may be the key indeed ! It's a difference with successful builds. However I now have like [internal errors…](https://gitlab.com/vindarel/abelujo-website/builds/732641) Many thanks